# How to properly use OR within SUMPRODUCT function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I am trying to program a cell to calculate how many alerts happen within a certain trading session.  I am using a 24 hour clock.  However, the trading sessions don't line up evenly with the clock.

- London (02:00:00 - 06:59:59) (COLOR CODED DK. BLUE)
- AFTER Hours 1 (16:00:00 - 11:59:59) (COMBINING BOTH AFTER HOURS SESSIONS AND COLOR CODED LT. BLUE)
- AFTER Hours 2 (00:00:01 - 01:59:59) (COMBINING BOTH AFTER HOURS SESSIONS AND COLOR CODED LT. BLUE)
  (These are represented within my spreadsheet.  For instance, London is AE5 and AF5.)

The difficulty has come in programming the AFTER Hours sessions calculation.  For the other sessions, I simply used =SUMPRODUCT(--($E$11:$E$61>=AE5),--($E$11:$E$61<=AF5)) for London where the E11:E61 represents the inputted alert times.  No troubles at all here.

Because of the AFTER Hours having two separate data entries, I thought an OR statement would be correct within a SUMPRODUCT function. AFTER HOURS 1 is represented by AE8 and AF8, while AFTER HOURS 2 is represented by AE9 and AF9.  Here is the SUMPRODUCT function that I have tried to use.

=SUMPRODUCT(--($E11:$E61>=$AE$8),--($E11:$E61<=$AF$8)+--($E11:$E61>=$AE$9),--($E11:$E61>=$AF$9))

It should be returning a 1, but comes up with a 0.  Not sure if I am missing something in the syntax or improperly using the + for the OR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would not it be sufficient to write two separate SUMPRODUCT functions and sum-up their results? =SUMPRODUCT(....)+SUMPRODUCT(...)

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT(--($E$11:$E$61>=$AA$8),--($E$11:$E$61<=$AB$8))+SUMPRODUCT(--($E$11:$E$61>=$AA$9),--($E$11:$E$61<=$AB$9)).    Is this the layout of the calculation that you believe is correct?  I did changed a couple of fields because I moved them to a better location.

Comment: I have tested this on a number of fields, and the above calculation is in fact the correct way to solve this issue.  Thanks @Me_me_me!!

Answer (score 0):

Given that the two conditions are mutually exclusive try like this

`=SUMPRODUCT(($E11:$E61>=$AE$8)*($E11:$E61<=$AF$8)+($E11:$E61>=$AE$9)*($E11:$E61>=$AF$9))`

Comment: @barry_houdini  I have entered a total number of 9 alerts, of which 1 alert falls at 1:09:00.  All others fall ouside the parameters of AFTER Hours 1 and AFTER Hours 2 above.  When I copy/paste the above calculation, I return an answer of 8 but it should be 1.  I am wondering if this calculation is capturing all but the 1 that it needs to capture?  Just a hunch, but don't know for sure.

Comment: @Brian White - this was based on the cell references and > or < symbols shown in your question, so I think the syntax is right, perhaps they are wrong (you have now reversed the last >= to be a <=) - given the formula you quote in your comment on Me_me_me's answer this version should give the same result: `=SUMPRODUCT(($E$11:$E$61>=$AA$8)*($E$11:$E$61<=$AB$8)+($E$11:$‌​E$61>=$AA$9)*($E$11:$E$61<=$AB$9))`